Abstract the async/await details away from calling code
I'm writing JavaScript to load information from an API.
I've written the following code:
export class Api {

    async #apiGet(endpoint) {
        const response = await fetch('/api/' + endpoint);
        return await response.json()
    }
    
    loadSavedItems() {
        const endpoint = 'saved-items/'
        return this.#apiGet(endpoint)
    }
}

What I want to do is to call loadSavedItems synchronously, and not have to use an await keyword. I'd like all knowledge of await/async/promises to be kept within the API class and not leak out into calling code.
However, in calling code I'm finding that I still need to use await in order to get the information. For example:
const api = new Api()

// this returns a Promise{<pending>} - I want it to just return a list of saved items
const savedItems = api.loadSavedItems()

// in order to get the list of saved items I have to use `await`
// which means this either has to be inside an async function or in the top level of a module
const actualSavedItems = await api.loadSavedItems()

Is there a way to abstract async/await from the calling code? Is this possible?

No it isn’t possible. You will always only be able to get its result back asynchronously either through a promise or a callback.

Your only options are to use async javascript and await, or use .then(callbackFunction) on the promise.

No, asynchronous execution cannot - and should not! - be hidden from the caller

Javascript doesn't provide a direct way to abstract away the async/await. But you can still do some modifications in code to minimize the exposure of async/await.You can use callbacks or event listeners to achieve the goal.
export class Api {

    async #apiGet(endpoint) {
        const response = await fetch('/api/' + endpoint);
        return await response.json()
    }
    
    loadSavedItems() {
        const endpoint = 'saved-items/'
       this.#apiGet(endpoint)
.then(data=>callback(data))
    .catch(error)
    }
}

And you can call it like this ->
const api = new Api();

api.loadSavedItems(savedItems => {
    
    console.log(savedItems);
});


Promised were introduced in order to replace asynchronous callback functions. Replacing async/await with callback functions is going back 15 years.

For the given code (because the promise might reject) the callback should be in the the form (err, result) and the .catch should pass through the error.

@jabaa promises where introduced to make it easier to work with asynchronous code in particular situations, e.g. error handling. await/async was introduced to make it easier to work with promises. But there are plenty of situations where callbacks for asynchronous processing are better then promises. But that always depends on the usecase.

@jabaa Generally, you are correct. But sometimes it makes sense to use Promise.one(...) or Promise.all(...) instead of async/await.

@ControlAltDel Please reread my comment. Promise.one and Promise.all use promises, not callbacks.

@t.niese I remember the pyramid of hell, but I don't know any advantages of callbacks over Promise.then. Do you have an example where a callback would be better than a promise?

@jabaa Don't get me wrong. I also use await/async as it makes many things more manageable. And await/async is great as long as you are aware that each created Promise has to be garbage collected and is queued in the microtask list, which could lead to particular problems with heavy load.  Regarding the callback hell  there was never a need to nest the callbacks; you were always able to have named functions listed in one scope and pass them by name. But await/async solved problems like loops and error handling.

@jabaa  Callbacks, for example, have advantages when it comes to pipelines/streaming, like processing huge amounts of data. With a promise-based approach, you often need to keep all the data you want to work on in memory. With a streaming-based approach, the data that has already been processed can be passed to its destination. You can, to some degree, replicate that with AsyncGernators. Anyway, what I want to say is that in many cases, one technique is not always better than another one; it just adds another tool that you can use to solve a problem.

@jabaa Some articles looking at the cost of await/ async: The Hidden Cost of async/await in Loops: A Real-World Scenario of Surging CPU Usage in Node.js, The Hidden Performance Cost of NodeJS and GraphQL, The Performance Overhead of JavaScript Promises and Async Await

@t.niese Ok, you're right. There are cases, where callbacks are better. I have to remember the performance overhead for the cases, when I have bottlenecks in the promises. I didn't know about it.
